# How do I get the Windows emoji keyboard to automatically dismiss after typing an emoji?

Tags: windows-10, emoji-keyboard

I'm loving the Windows 10 emoji keyboard.
(type the keyboard combination `Win + .` to access it)

[image: Windows Emoji Keyboard]

Only problem is it doesn't close after selecting a character.  You have to hit the `Escape` key to dismiss.

**How do you set it to dismiss immediately after selecting an emoji?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's a setting for this:

1. Open **Settings**
2. Search for "keyboard" and select **Edit language and keyboard options**
3. On the right side, click **Advanced keyboard settings**
4. Towards the bottom, uncheck **Don't close the panel automatically after an emoji has been entered**

[image: advanced keyboard settings]

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to do this in Windows 11? This option seems to have vanished.

Comment: Linking to @jeffmaher's own question here: https://superuser.com/q/1698523/954098
Bottom line is there's no elegant way to do it, but if you keep typing (press 'spacebar') the panel will go away.