# How to get the Windows 11 emoji panel to automatically close after typing one emoji?

Tags: keyboard, windows-11, input, emoji, emoji-keyboard

The Windows 11 emoji panel/picker/keyboard (opened by <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>) stays open after I type one emoji, allowing me to keep entering emojis. I'd prefer that the panel closes after I type one emoji because I don't usually enter more than one at a time.

How do I configure Windows 11 to close the emoji panel after a single emoji is entered, and return focus to normal character entry? (i.e. mimicking similar behaviour from mobile devices or macOS's emoji pickers)

*Note: Windows 10 had this configurability in 'Advanced Keyboard Settings', but that option no longer appears (as indicated in [this SuperUser question that covers Windows 10](https://superuser.com/questions/1340955/how-do-i-get-the-windows-emoji-keyboard-to-automatically-dismiss-after-typing-an)).*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you go on typing, the emoji keyboard closes by itself.

I found this out accidentally but I now use this as a practical workaround.

Answer (score 5):

TLDR; **There is no elegant workaround** for this as of now.

---

It is worth mentioning that the registry key for enabling/disabling this functionality is still available - however, it is sadly **not functional**...

It is located under: `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Input\Settings` REG_DWORD

Hopefully this will be reimplemented the same way as the toolbar position feature is supposed to be (ie place the toolbar at the top of the screen).

*(I would have added this as a comment if I had the reputation. Please don't remove this answer, as it is useful for people like me, who thought there was an easy workaround.)*

Answer (score 3):

> How do I configure Windows 11 to close the emoji panel after a single
> emoji is entered,

I have double checked 2 Windows 11 Pro machines - one Production and one Insider and both up to date.

What you see is the normal behavior of Windows 11 and not alterable.

The emoji dialogue box opens, allow you to select one or more emojis, and then you close the box.

So that is new (compared to older operating systems) and it is worth noting that Windows 11 is (in very round numbers) about half as configurable as prior systems.