# On Windows, is there an equivalent to the MacOS system-wide emoji selector overlay (cmd+opt+space)?

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts, emoji, emoji-keyboard

On MacOS, if you hit the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> when a text field is highlighted, a window pops up with a searchable emoji selector:

[image: Emoji picker on macOS]

Some apps have opted into the convention of displaying an emoji selector when you start a word with ":", like WhatsApp:

[image: Whatsapp emoji picker]

Obviously, this is app specific so it's not system wide functionality.

Does Windows have a system wide emoji selector?

If not, is there a third party app that adds that capability to Windows?

I am referring to Windows 10 or Windows 11

Comment: there are so many duplicates: [Shortcut to pop up emoji window automatically](https://superuser.com/q/1712502/241386), [Windows 10 equivalent of Mac `Command+Control+Space`](https://superuser.com/q/1628332/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Windows 10 and 11, you use the combination of <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>. See image below.

[image: Emoji window in Windows 11]

Comment: [Win]+'.'  works the same but at least on 10, they aren't very pretty.  Not sure about 11.  We hates it too much to even fire up a VM and check.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas `Win`+`.` works also on Windows 11.

Comment:  Thanks, this is great. Doesn't seem to auto close when you pick an emoji, but at least it works!

Comment: @DavidAlsh obviously it does, if you change the settings https://i.stack.imgur.com/XkucJ.png

Comment: I just upgraded to Windows 11 and that option doesn't seem to be available in the new settings, any ideas? https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHBx0.png

Comment: Oh, you can't https://superuser.com/questions/1698523/how-to-get-the-windows-11-emoji-panel-to-automatically-close-after-typing-one-em

Comment: This article (which I didn't write) pretty much sums it up: [_Emoji Panel is part of Windows that totally sucks_](https://office-watch.com/2022/emoji-panel-windows-10-totally-sucks/).

Comment: @phuclv many, many thanks for the tip about auto-closing the emoji-panel! This improves the usability by an order of magnitude.